# Segmentation fault when trying to receive from client

Tags: c++, udp

The following piece of code is giving me errors. A segmentation fault occurs whenever I execute it.

```
bool handshake() {
    node recv;
    void *ptr = recv;
    recverror = recvfrom(sock,(void*) recv, sizeof((void *) recv), 0, (struct sockaddr*)&from, &len);
    cout << recv.data; 
    return true;
}
```

This is the structure of the node:

```
struct node {
    char *data;
    int size_data;
    int dest_port;
    int src_port;
    int flag;
    double checksum;
    int seq;
    int ack;
    int windowsize;
    node* next;
    node() {next = NULL;}
};
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several big problems with your code:

First, the assignment of `ptr` is incorrect, it should be:

```
void *ptr = &recv;
```

You should have gotten a compiler error regarding a type mismatch from your code.

Next, your arguments to `recvfrom` are wrong:

```
recverror = recvfrom(sock, ptr, sizeof(recv), 0, (struct sockaddr*)&from, &len);
```

You can't convert a struct to a pointer, you want to pass the address of the struct.

Finally, and most significantly, it doesn't make sense to have `char*` members in a structure that's being passed over the network. Pointers only make sense within a single process, you can't pass them between processes or machines. You need to [serialize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) your data before putting it on the wire.

Answer (score 0):

`void *ptr = recv` is wrong. Instead do `void *ptr = &recv`.